# Powershell script to remove users from distribution groups

Tags: powershell, email, exchange-server

I'm trying to find a solution to remove a user from all the distribution groups they are in. I found this script but am running into issues:

```
$email = Read-Host "Please provide a user's email address to remove from all distribution groups"
$mailbox = Get-Mailbox -Identity $email
$DN=$mailbox.DistinguishedName
$Filter = "Members -like ""$DN"""
$DistributionGroupsList = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter $Filter
Write-host `n
Write-host "Listing all Distribution Groups:"
Write-host `n
$DistributionGroupsList | ft
$answer = Read-Host "Would you like to proceed and remove $email from all distribution groups ( y / n )?" 
While ("y","n" -notcontains $answer) {
    $answer = Read-Host "Would you like to proceed and remove $email from all distribution groups ( y / n )?"
    }
If ($answer -eq 'y') {
    ForEach ($item in $DistributionGroupsList) {
        Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $item.DisplayName –Member $email –BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck -Confirm:$false
    }
    
    Write-host `n
    Write-host "Successfully removed"
    Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
Else
    {
    Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
```

It will get to the stage where it lists all the groups a user is in and asks whether or not to remove them, however it seems to get stuck on the –BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck advising that there is an issue with this parameter.

Comment: "advising that there is an issue with this parameter." - is the advise that a parameter of that name doesn't exist? Maybe post the full error message?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Here's the error:   A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck'.  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-DistributionGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Remove-DistributionGroupMember
    + PSComputerName        : exch2016-01.accord.local

Comment: So remove it :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen How would that look? Already tried removing it but I just get more errors in its place.

Comment: ... and what do the errors say? Please be mindful that no one else can see your screen, "more errors" doesn't tell us anything :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen So now the error reads: Remove-DistributionGroupMember : Missing an argument for parameter 'Member'. Specify a parameter of type
'System.Object' and try again.
At line:16 char:68
+ ... e-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $item.DisplayName –Member -Confir ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-DistributionGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Remove-DistributionGroupMember

Comment: looks like your accidentally removed `$email` from the statement. It should read `Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $item.DisplayName –Member $email -Confirm:$false`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I also get this error if I just remove the '–BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck' - You don't have sufficient permissions. This operation can only be performed by a manager of the group.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-DistributionGroupMember], OperationRequiresGroupManagerExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=EXCH2016-01,RequestId=ae3c7f93-e204-4245-aa5f-8678ff68aa63,TimeStamp=19/11/2021

Comment: I'll try that thanks :)

Comment: Tried that @MathiasR.Jessen but I'm getting the above error

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the `-` in front of `BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck` in your script is not a hyphen but an [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash) (which explains the first error). Replace it with: `Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $item.DisplayName -Member $email -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck -Confirm:$false` (copy-paste it)

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen getting somewhere but now got a new error. Think it might just be checking one mail server? The operation couldn't be performed because object 'rebecca.edge@greensqaureaccord.co.uk' couldn't be found on
'DCWESTBROM01.accord.local'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=EXCH2016-01,RequestId=ae3c7f93-e204-4245-aa5f-8678ff68aa63,[FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] 4EA0476A,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetMailbox

Comment: The dash befire `–Member` is also not a hyphen. Retype that as well

Answer (score 0):

I found this article on Microsoft TechCenter forum... obviously you'll need to expand it to meet your needs. - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/99c1f07b-12fa-4e06-95bd-246a757bb00f/powershellscript-to-remove-all-group-memberships-for-one-user

```
$DGs= Get-DistributionGroup | where { (Get-DistributionGroupMember $_ | foreach {$_.PrimarySmtpAddress}) -contains "user@domain.com"}
 
foreach( $dg in $DGs){
Remove-DistributionGroupMember $dg -Member user@domain.com
}
```

Comment: Thanks I actually found the same script and managed to get this one working with no issues

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments on the fact the - are not the same you could just open the script in PowerShell ISE or VisualStudio Code and then next to each command as you write it out you can press Tab on your keyboard and it would correct would if the parameters work with that command. But yes I would say based on your last comment

> The operation couldn't be performed because object 'rebecca.edge@greensqaureaccord.co.uk' couldn't be found on 'DCWESTBROM01.accord.local'. + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=EXCH2016-01,RequestId=ae3c7f93-e204-4245-aa5f-8678ff68aa63,[FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException] 4EA0476A,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetMailbox

That the email doesn't exist. I tested the script replacing all the dashes with correct ones (best done in Notepad to avoid formatting) and seems to work without error for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $UserToRemove = "username@domain.com"
 
Try {
    #Connect to Exchange Online
    Connect-ExchangeOnline
 
    #Get All Distribution Lists - Excluding Mail enabled security groups
    $DistributionGroups = Get-Distributiongroup -resultsize unlimited |  Where {!$_.GroupType.contains("SecurityEnabled")}
 
    #Loop through each Distribution Lists
    ForEach ($Group in $DistributionGroups)
    {
        #Check if the Distribution List contains the particular user
        If ((Get-DistributionGroupMember $Group.Name | Select -Expand PrimarySmtpAddress) -contains $UserToRemove)
        {
            Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Group.Name -Member $UserToRemove -Confirm:$false
            Write-host "Removed user from group '$Group'" -f Green
        }
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
}


#Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2021/02/microsoft-365-remove-user-from-all-distribution-groups-using-powershell.html#ixzz838p7Az7z
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [answer]. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).